bwrap: execvp com.github.tchx84.Flatseal: No such file or directory flatpak
Some background of what happened.
I was playing with Flatseal to try few themes on my flatpak appliacations, and after some workarounds here and there, I accidently removed some file section in the global applications settings, I do not remember what was the field exactly. TO correct everything, I tapped resent settings, and later closed the app. After that, clicking any(literally all) of my flatpak applications stopped opening, so I tried to open them from terminal, and running any application produced the following lines
bwrap: execvp com.github.tchx84.Flatseal: No such file or directory
On running the application with --verbose produced following output in the case of Flatseal,
F: No installations directory in /etc/flatpak/installations.d. Skipping
F: Opening system flatpak installation at path /var/lib/flatpak
F: Opening user flatpak installation at path /home/me/.local/share/flatpak
F: Opening user flatpak installation at path /home/me/.local/share/flatpak
F: Opening system flatpak installation at path /var/lib/flatpak
F: Skipping parental controls check for app/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal/x86_64/stable since parental controls are disabled globally
F: Opening user flatpak installation at path /home/me/.local/share/flatpak
F: Opening system flatpak installation at path /var/lib/flatpak
F: /var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/{A BIG number appeared}/files/lib32 does not exist
F: Cleaning up unused container id 1497037892
F: Cleaning up per-app-ID state for com.tominlab.wonderpen
F: Allocated instance id 411947855
F: Add defaults in dir /com/github/tchx84/Flatseal/
F: Add locks in dir /com/github/tchx84/Flatseal/
F: Disallowing network access
F: Allowing dri access
F: Allowing homedir access
F: Allowing wayland access
F: Running '/usr/libexec/flatpak-bwrap --args 39 -- /usr/libexec/flatpak-dbus-proxy --args=41'
F: Running '/usr/libexec/flatpak-bwrap --args 39 -- com.github.tchx84.Flatseal'
bwrap: execvp com.github.tchx84.Flatseal: No such file or directory


I have followed this ,but didn't understand.
I have already tried a ton of things and listing them as I remember.

I have tried running flatpak repair, flatpak update.
I have tried removing org.gnome.Platform as somewhere suggested but it didn't happen as applications were dependent on it.
I have completely removed the configuration file and removed and reinstalled whole flatpak.
I have updated the run times after reinstallation and it did some reinstallation of refs which were not found.

I have already tried the following(restating again, compressed form of my gpt conversation)
Actions Taken:
Restarted System:
Reinstalled Flatpak:
    Removed Flatpak completely.
    Reinstalled Flatpak.
Updated Flatpak and System:
    Ensured all packages and Flatpak were up-to-date.
Checked Permissions:
    Verified that apps had necessary permissions.
Run Apps from Terminal:
    Apps have begin to stop running from the terminal with mentioned issue.
Investigated Log Files:
    Checked logs for any errors or warnings.
Checked Flatpak Configuration:
    Ensured Flatpak configuration was correct.

If asked will try to share the log entry
Please ask for any other relevant information required.

I don't know if it would be of any use but just before the telegram flatpak stopped working, its download folder path got to temporary folder for its location I specified earlier. Also on again redefining the path, it was not coming like home/name/downloads/.... but like user/run/....

Changing some settings here and there, few paths and variables (what I could deduce) got hampered in Flatseal which prevented any application(including Flatseal) to open and causing bwarp to give errors. If any other person faces the same problem, resetting the things is the only way things worked for me.
flatpak override --reset --user

But it should be noted that this command resets the configurations, causing previous changes in configs to potentially loose.
